# Local variable error in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to create a comments section for a web page. However, the function I used in my views.py file returns an error: "Local variable referenced before assignment." Here is the code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.template import RequestContext




class CommentForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)



    def clean_message(self):

        message = self.cleaned_data['message']

        num_words = len(message.split())

        return message



def comment(request):
    commentlist = []

    errors = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.cleaned_data
            commentlist.append(comment)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()    
    initialData = ({'form': form, 'commentlist': commentlist, 'comment': comment})

    csrfContext = RequestContext(request, initialData)

    return render_to_response('hello_world.htm', csrfContext)
```

Here is my template, called "hello_world.htm":

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.errorlist{

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

}



.errorlist li{

background-color: red;

color: white;

display: block;

font-size: 10px;

margin: 0 0 3px;

padding: 4px 5px;

}



.field

{

background-color:#E2F2F2;

border: white 1px solid;

padding: 5px;

width: 80%;

font-family: Arial;

}


.field2

{

background-color:#E2F2E2;

border: white 1px solid;

padding: 5px;

width: 80%;

font-family: Arial;

}


.header

{

background-color:#E2E2F2;

border: white 1px solid;

padding: 5px;

width: 80%;

font-family: Arial;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="field2">
Comments:
</div>
{% for comment in commentlist %}
<div class="field2">
{{ comment }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% if form.errors %}

<p style="color: red;"><b>Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.  </b></p>

{% endif %}
<div class="field"><b>Want to comment?</b></div>

<form action="" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}

<div class="field">

{{ form.name.errors }}

<label for="id_subject">Name:</label>

{{ form.name }}

</div>

<div class="field">

{{ form.email.errors }}

<label for="id_email">Your e-mail address</label>

{{ form.email }}

</div>

<div class="field">

{{ form.comment.errors }}

<p>Comment:</p>

{{ form.comment }}

<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
```

How can I rewrite my views.py (particularly the "comments" function) so that this error will not come up? Sorry if there are many errors in my code, I have only been working with Django for a few days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one variable that *might* not be assigned, depending on how the *if* statements fire: `comment`. Set it to null or something to start:

```
def comment(request):
    commentlist = []
    comment = ''
```

And *rename* the function to something else, maybe `get_comment()` - it's a bad idea to have variables the same name as functions.

Also, for debugging the `commentlist` variable - try setting it in the *else* statement, just to see if you're handling the `GET` correctly:

```
    else: #form invalid
        commentlist = ['bad form']
else:
    form = CommentForm()
    commentlist = ['testing']
```

Update - wups, I just noticed you had both `comment` and `commentlist` in the template dictionary. Take out comment:

```
initialData = ({'form': form, 'commentlist': commentlist}
```

Otherwise I suspect that it's interfering with the `comment` variable in the template.

Update 2 - sigh. I didn't read the code closely enough - you have an `HttpResponseRedirect` right after assigning `commentlist` - so the list is never set and passed to `render_to_response`. If you're thinking that `commentlist` will be built up over several calls - it *won't*, because you're setting it to an empty list at the start of the function. Basically, you need to re-write all of the logic. :)

Or you could try commenting out the `HttpResponseRedirect`, and let it fall through to the `render_to_response` line.

Comment: That solves the problem of the error, but when one submits a comment it does not appear on the page.

Comment: As I just added to my post, try re-naming either the function or variable, I'm not sure if that might cause a problem. Also, in the template - just print out `{{ commentlist }}`, make sure it *has* data.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't append the comment to "commentlist", even after renaming the "comment" variable to "comment1". Do you know why that could be? (Sorry I'm asking so much - I'm a programming novice.)

Comment: I think the function ignores the "if" statements and prints commentlist as []. How could I rewrite the function so that "comment1" doesn't depend on these if statements? Is it possible?

Comment: OK. I'll just rewrite the function and try linking "commentlist" to a database (so that it can be built up over time). Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome - did you see my last update about removing the redirect? Although it might fix the immediate problem, it *won't* allow you to build up a list of multiple comments - as you said, you would need to store them in a database.

Comment: Yes I used your advice from the last update, and now it returns a function object (not exactly what I intended, but I can make it work). I'm working on my database right now. :)

Comment: I'm not sure a function object is the best way to go, either. :) But explaining how to change the data model is too complex for a comment. Have you seen the [Django Book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/)? It's worth reading through, and might make it easier to redesign this program.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of reading it, but I'm only on Chapter 8. After I'm done reading the book, I'll continue working on the code. For now I'll just give it a break.